Elasticsearch Go Client Error: "Invalid JSON format: EOF" when indexing documents in Middleware
I'm developing a middleware in Go that intercepts HTTP requests, reads JSON data from the request body, and indexes it as a document in Elasticsearch based on this documentation.
However, although the document appears to be indexed in Elasticsearch, the process returns an Invalid JSON format: EOF error. This error prevents the middleware from proceeding to the main handler that performs additional database operations.
Here is the relevant part of my middleware code:
package middlewares

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/elastic/go-elasticsearch/v8"
    "github.com/elastic/go-elasticsearch/v8/typedapi/types"
    "github.com/google/uuid"
)

// IndexDocumentMiddleware creates a middleware to index documents into Elasticsearch
func IndexDocumentMiddleware(es *elasticsearch.TypedClient) func(http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return func(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
        return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            ctx := r.Context()
            // Read and decode the request body into a generic map to determine the type of document
            var doc map[string]interface{}
            if err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&doc); err != nil {
                http.Error(w, "Error parsing request body", http.StatusBadRequest)
                return
            }

            var indexName string
            if typeName, ok := doc["type"].(string); ok {
                indexName = typeName
            } else {
                http.Error(w, "Error: 'type' is not a string or is missing", http.StatusBadRequest)
                return
            }

            existsRes, err := es.Indices.Exists(indexName).Do(ctx)
            if err != nil {
                http.Error(w, "Error existsRes: "+err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
                return
            }

            if !existsRes {
                _, err := es.Indices.Create(indexName).Mappings(types.NewTypeMapping()).Do(ctx)
                if err != nil {
                    http.Error(w, "Error creating index: "+err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
                    return
                }
            }

            docID := uuid.New().String()

            _, err = es.Index(indexName).
                Id(docID).
                Document(doc).Do(ctx)
            if err != nil {
                http.Error(w, "Error indexing document: "+err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
                return
            }

            next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
        })
    }
}

Insomnia req / res

Document on Kibana

Specific Questions:

What could be causing the "Invalid JSON format: EOF" error even though the document seems to be indexed successfully?
How can I ensure that the JSON data is properly handled and no errors are returned so that the middleware can proceed to the main handler?

Any insights or suggestions to address this issue would be greatly appreciated!

You read the request body in the middleware without replacing it afterward. My guess is that another handler tries to read it again, but you cannot read the body more than once. To fix this replace the request body in the middleware with a fresh copy after reading it: use io.ReadAll and json.Unmarshal or io.TeeReader with bytes.Buffer in the middleware, then use io.NopCloser(bytes.NewReader(b)) or io.NopCloser(buf) to create a new ReadCloser).

Thanks a lot, @Peter! So much helpful! I wasn’t aware that reading the HTTP request body would consume it, leaving nothing for the next handlers.

Answer:.Decode(&doc)→ Decoding Makes Body Empty
This issue arises because when you read from http.Request.Body, which is an io.ReadCloser, the data is consumed and is not available for subsequent reads. Apparently, this is a common mistake, especially when multiple handlers or middleware need to access the request body.
To fix this, you need to read the entire body first, and then restore it so that it can be re-read by subsequent handlers or middleware. Here’s the essential piece of code that accomplishes this:
// Read the entire body
bodyBytes, err := io.ReadAll(r.Body)
if err != nil {
    http.Error(w, "Error reading request body", http.StatusInternalServerError)
    return
}
// Restore the io.ReadCloser to its original state
r.Body = io.NopCloser(bytes.NewBuffer(bodyBytes))

//code continues...
// Read and decode the request body into a generic map to determine the type of document
var doc map[string]interface{} //...


Explanation:

Consuming the Body: The json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&doc) operation reads the entire contents of the io.ReadCloser stream. Once read, the stream is empty because io.ReadCloser does not support rewinding. This effectively "consumes" the body, making it empty for any subsequent attempts to read it.

Restoring the Body: After reading, r.Body is re-assigned using io.NopCloser(bytes.NewBuffer(bodyBytes)). This line creates a new io.ReadCloser from the bodyBytes we read earlier, effectively duplicating the original content. io.NopCloser is used to convert an io.Reader (returned by bytes.NewBuffer) into an io.ReadCloser without adding any functionality to close, as the buffer does not need to be closed.


This approach ensures that any middleware or handler that runs after this code will still have access to the full request body as if it were untouched.
Why This Is Important:
Not handling the request body correctly can lead to subtle bugs, especially in larger applications where multiple parts of the middleware chain may need to inspect or modify the request. This technique ensures that all parts of your HTTP server can operate correctly without interfering with each other.
